# Why docker can't connect to host while running Gitlab runner?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm getting this error output from gitlab runner I have installed locally:

> error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dproject-0%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=0": dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.1.254:53: no such host
> Test failed:  users users-lint client
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
>
> FATAL: exit code 1

my `config.toml` file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "tdd"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "redacted_XXXXXXXX"
  executor = "docker"
  builds_dir = "~/tdd"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    cache_dir = ""
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
```

taking a look at `.gitlab-ci.yml` file may help:

```yaml
image: docker:stable

# services:
#    - docker:dind


variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  POSTGRES_DB: users_dev
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  POSTGRES_HOST: postgres


stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add --no-cache --update python3-dev py3-pip curl
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.3/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1
  - export SECRET_KEY=hakuna000matata

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sh test.sh
```

I commented out `services` because it works OK for CI environment but threads on the web suggests that it's better to keep it off when running the build locally.
Any ideas what may help ? I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: `any ideas what may help ?` => to understand your problem? Your `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file. The error is from a job no one has a single clue about. As a guess, you are trying to build an image in docker-in-docker and the service is not started/declared/configured correctly.

Comment: **Warning**: you should renew that gitlab.com runner token right now!

Comment: I've added `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for review.

Comment: @Zeitounator the token isn't complete.  :)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Currently, you are mounting your local docker socket to every container that your runner starts as if you wanted to build images from the local docker engine with docker socket binding. But you are not using it in your build since you try to reach a dind service that you are not starting since it is commented out. You need to decide how you want to build docker images from your jobs and fix the configuration accordingly => https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html